# Найти минимальное четное значение

Tags: java

Как вывести "ошибка" если нет минимальных четных значений? И что делать, если x[0] будет нечётным.
'''

```
 min = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
            if ((x[i] % 2 == 0) && (x[i] < x[min])) {
                min = i;
            }
         }
        System.out.printf("Минимальное значение: x(%d)= %1.2f\n", min, x[min]);
```

'''

Comment: сделать `min = -1;`, а потом после цикла проверять, что если min == -1, значит нет чётных значений

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; //нечётное
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if ((x[i] % 2 == 0) && (x[i] < min)) {
            min = x[i];
        }
     }
```

А в конце уже проверить `min` на чётность или совпадение с `Integer.MAX_VALUE` и соответственно сделать вывод

Или так:

```
    min = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        if (x[i] % 2 == 0) {
             if (x[min] % 2 != 0)  || (x[i] < x[min])) {
                 min = i;
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: а как сделать без  min = Integer.MAX_VALUE

Comment: Это обычная практика. Чем не подходит?

Comment: мне нужно именно через x[0](через индексы), чтобы массив шел с x[1] и проверялся по условию

Comment: @user388671 "чтобы массив шел с x[1]" - ??

Comment: Привёл вариант с использованием x[0]. В конце опять же проверить на чётность.

Comment: оо, все спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

красиво через стримы

```
Arrays.stream(x)
        .filter(a -> a % 2 == 0)
        .min()
        .ifPresentOrElse(
                min -> System.out.println("Минимальное четное : " + min),
                () -> System.out.println("Нет минимального четного")
        );
```

Comment: спасибо большое